# No Value given for one or more requirement parameters

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

Plz tell me where I am doing wrong, I am copying the part of code having trouble

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_KEEPER WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]) = ?";

 DataSet dataSet=new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter=new OleDbDataAdapter();
            try
            {
                if(OpenOledbConnection())
                {
                    dataAdapter.SelectCommand=new OleDbCommand(query,connection);
                    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]", date.Month);
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
                    // checking if dataset is updated or not
                    int temp = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    return dataSet;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error While Retrieving data by Month");

            }
            finally
            {
                CloseOledbConnection();
            }
            return null;
```

Thanks in Advance

MGD

Comment: If you actually want an answer, you will not be able to get around having to ask an actual question.

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?  Please tell us whether it's a compiler or runtime error, or simply not getting what you expect.  In the latter case, please be specific about what you expect and what you get; otherwise, quote the error.

Comment: My question is actually the error text "No Value given for one or more requirement parameters" and its run time error when i try to execute the query, thanks for ur time but the solution u provide didnt make any change, m having the same error i ve mentioned above, and kindly tell me wat exactly do u mean by "@x" is it the variable name m passing in the function or the columns name ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_KEEPER WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]) = ?";
```

write

```
query = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_KEEPER WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]) = @x";
```

and instead of

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]", date.Month);
```

write

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", date.Month);
```